xsl processor xsltproc. What is the proper way to use --stringparam?
I am a trying to pass the value of a shell variable to an xsltproc instance. The file text.xsl contains:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:import href="file:/Users/robertramey/WorkingProjects/modular-boost/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="file:$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
#functions as expected
$echo $BOOST_ROOT
/Users/robertramey/WorkingProjects/modular-boost
#passes on first import as expected.
#but fails on the second as expect as BOOST_ROOT is not set
$xsltproc --maxdepth 6000 --xinclude --nonet test.xsl
warning: failed to load external entity "file:$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"
#passes on the first import as expected
#fails on the second - NOT expected
$xsltproc --maxdepth 6000 --stringparam BOOST_ROOT "/Users/robertramey/WorkingProjects/modular-boost" --xinclude --nonet test.xsl
warning: failed to load external entity "file:$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"
compilation error: file test.xsl line 4 element import
xsl:import : unable to load file:$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl
Why is this? What do I have to do to make this work?
$cat bb2db.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="https://www.boost.org/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
which works.  But it relies on a global URL to find the file to import.  This makes my script dependent on having an internet connection which I'd prefer to avoid.  I'd like to refer to a local directory:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href=file:"$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
Since the shell variable holds the base path of the desired xml stylysheet I want to import.

I don't think parameterizing an xsl:import is possible with XSLT 1. With XSLT 3 (like SaxonC 12 HE) you might be able to use a static parameter (<xsl:param name="BOOST_ROOT" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'/Users/robertramey/WorkingProjects/modular-boost'"/>) and a shadow attribute (<xsl:import _href="file:{$BOOST_ROOT}/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl"/>).

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve by your attempt to parameterise the xsl:import? What is the reason why you don't just import the file directly?

I expanded the question to include this information.  Thanks for helping me out with this!

I think your question could be divided into two: (1) how to pass a parameter to an XSLT stylesheet and (2) how to use the parameter in xsl:import. Since the answer to #2 is that you can't (because the href attribute of  xsl:import is not an attribute value template) the first part becomes moot.

I am not a heavy xsltproc users but I would suggest to check whether using a catalog https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsltproc can't help you resolve a HTTPS URL like https://www.boost.org/tools/boostbook/xsl/docbook.xsl to your local file URL. Or of course consider moving to XSLT 3, both SaxonC 12 for C/C++ https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml or the Node.js SaxonJS/xslt3 command line tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3 should support the approach with a static parameter and a shadow attribute.

Looks like I may have it!!!!:  xsltproc --maxdepth 6000 --path "$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl" --xinclude --nonet test.xsl

Looks like I may have it!!!!:  xsltproc --maxdepth 6000 --path "$BOOST_ROOT/tools/boostbook/xsl" --xinclude --nonet test.xsl
test.xsl contains:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="xsl/docbook.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
